# SubclassWindow() function assert

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Its c++ developer want to learn more about vc++. :)

One concept called subclassing is one milestone i have. Basically i go through the following article of codeproject [Create your own controls - the art of subclassing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/480/Create-your-own-controls-the-art-of-subclassing) its interesting and i understand greatly.

But when i execute same with visual studio 2010 i get assertion at following point.

```
CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDOK); // or use some other method to get
                                      // a pointer to the window you wish
                                      // to subclass
ASSERT( pWnd && pWnd->GetSafeHwnd() );
m_OkButton.SubclassWindow(pWnd->GetSafeHwnd()); //Assertion point.
```

Please note above code is placed in OnInitDialog() function and [image]

Comment: Just tried the sample project in the codeproject article. It works perfectly fine on my VS2010.

Comment: @MichaelWalz what about http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113421 ??

Comment: @Sankaganak The link you provided applies to **Microsoft Visual C++ 4.0 Standard Edition** and earlier. That product is more than 15 years old.

Comment: *"Press Retry to debug the application"* - Did you try? Did you inspect the callstack? With the information you provided there is no way to answer the question. It's also somewhat odd to call `SubclassWindow` when a simple `DDX_Control` entry in your `DoDataExchange` method suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar experiences.

This code seems causing the error

```
VERIFY(m_Edit.SubclassWindow(parent->GetSafeHwnd()));
```

Change to this line,everything would be ok.

```
m_Edit.SubclassDlgItem(nId,parent);
```